# Excel. Creating charts in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I need to create one chart per sheet in Excel. Here is my code:

```
    Sheets(i).Activate

    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        cht.Delete
    Next

    'create chart
    Set chtChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=75, Width:=300, Top:=75, Height:=300).Chart
    With chtChart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth

        Do While .SeriesCollection.Count <> 0
            Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
                .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
            Loop
        Loop

        Set srsNew = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With srsNew
            .XValues = "='" & Sheets(i).Name & "'!" & _
            Sheets(i).Range(Range("K2"), Range("k2").End(xlDown)).Address
            .Values = "='" & Sheets(i).Name & "'!" & _
            Sheets(i).Range(Range("l2"), Range("l2").End(xlDown)).Address
        End With
    End With
```

For the first sheet this works but for the second, third ... it does not. It issues the error 1004 "application defined or object defined error" in XValues or Values. I also noticed that if I introduce

```
range("K2")
```

outside the with block I get an error in the second, third .... sheets but not in the first one.

Any advise is most welcome

Regards

João

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Qualify your `Range`s with sheets they belong to.
2. Don't use `Select` or `ActiveSheet`.
3. Don't build up the string address. Use ranges directly.

```
Dim CurSheet As Worksheet, cht As ChartObject
Dim chtChart As Chart, srsNew As Series

...

Set CurSheet = Worksheets(i)

For Each cht In CurSheet.ChartObjects
  cht.Delete
Next


'create chart
Set chtChart = CurSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=75, Width:=300, Top:=75, Height:=300).Chart
With chtChart
  .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth

  Do While .SeriesCollection.Count <> 0
    .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
  Loop

  Set srsNew = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  With srsNew
    .XValues = CurSheet.Range(CurSheet.Range("k2"), CurSheet.Range("k2").End(xlDown))
    .Values = CurSheet.Range(CurSheet.Range("l2"), CurSheet.Range("l2").End(xlDown))
  End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help if you fully qualified those Ranges like this:

```
With srsNew
    .XValues = "='" & Sheets(i).Name & "'!" & _
    Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Range("K2"), Sheets(i).Range("k2").End(xlDown)).Address
    .Values = "='" & Sheets(i).Name & "'!" & _
    Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Range("l2"), Sheets(i).Range("l2").End(xlDown)).Address
End With
```